# How to set arrows at the end of Core Plot axis?

Tags: plot, core-plot

I found Core Plot as very nice plotting library.
But there is small issue: I can not find any way to set directional arrows at the end of axis for plots.
Am I missing something here maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by Core Plot yet. You can add an enhancement request at the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list). No guarantees on when something like this will be implemented, but an open issue will keep it on the radar.

In the meantime, you could fake it using a plot space annotation to position your own arrow at the proper spot. The annotation content could be `CPTLayer` with a background image of the arrow or a custom (i.e., built by you) `CPTLayer` that draws the arrow.

Eric

Comment: do you know know is this feature is implemented ?

Comment: This was added to Core Plot shortly after my answer here. It should appear in Core Plot releases 0.9 and later. There is a demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app.