# Arrow at the end of the graph with corePlot?

Tags: ios, graphics, core-plot

is it possible to add an arrow on the graph like that with corePlot ?

[image]

Comment: As an answer, are you looking for one of "Yes, it is." or "No, it isn't"?

Comment: I'm looking for a "Yes, it is" with some ways to do it :-)

Comment: This post answer to my question :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749035/how-to-set-arrows-at-the-end-of-core-plot-axis

Comment: [You can draw it using Quartz.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343138/how-to-find-an-arrow-tip-points-given-origin-and-end-point-of-a-line/12343265#12343265)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only on axis lines. See the *Plot Gallery* example app for several examples.

Comment: I've seen it thank you !